# Can't get ListBox and UpdateTarget to work

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, listbox

Here are the relevant parts of the XAML file:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingTest"
<ListBox x:Name="myList"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MyClass.Dic},
                               Path=Keys,
                               Mode=OneWay,
                               UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}">
</ListBox>
```

MyClass is a public static class and Dic is a static public property, a  Dictionary.

At a certain point I add items to the Dictionary and would like the ListBox to reflect the changes.
This is the code I thought about using but it doesn't work:

```
BindingExpression binding;
binding = myList.GetBindingExpression(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty);
binding.UpdateTarget();
```

This code instead works:

```
myList.ItemsSource = null;
myList.ItemsSource = MyClass.dic.Keys;
```

I would prefer to use UpdateTarget, but I can't get it to work.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Binding of items is handled rather differently than standard binding of `DependencyProperty`s in WPF (specifically, by `ItemsControl`s).

I think you want something like the following:

```
var itemsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myListBox.ItemsSource);
itemsView.Refresh()
```

It is in fact the `ICollectionView` object that you want to refresh. This effectively is the object that manages the collection binding for you. See [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the previous answer by Noldorin, you can hook to the PropertyChanged event to make this happen automatically anytime your model is updated:

```
public partial class YourView {
  public YourView () {
    InitializeComponent();
    ViewModel=YourDataObject;
    ViewModel.PropertyChanged+=OnUpdateYourDataObject;
  }
  public YourDataObject? ViewModel {
    get => DataContext as YourDataObject;
    set => DataContext=value;
  }
  public void OnUpdateYourDataObject(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs? e) => 
        CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(YourListBox.ItemsSource).Refresh();
 }
```

Replace YourDataObject and YourListBox with the correct values. This will automatically update your view whenever a property on your object changes. I'm not sure why this isn't handled automatically but I couldn't figure out the setting to make that work.